# Deploy an existing release to a skipped environment in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have azure devops yaml base pipeline with a start stage of build and publish artifact then a dev stage dependent of the build stage and a uat stage dependent on dev and a prod stage dependent on uat.

I ran the pipeline with deselecting(skip) the prod pipeline so that everything runs till uat stage.

At a certain point when UAT is over, I want to deploy the same release on prod but there is no option to specifically deploy it on prod. If I create a new release, it will start from beginning. This was quite easy in classic pipeline where you can get a deploy any stage at any time.

Please note, I can rerun a successful or failed stage as there come a button under each stage in a give release to rerun but not for the skipped one.

I have tried removing the uat dependency from prod but it doesn't work as well.

I can put a gate and keep it waiting for a long time but that is not something I am looking for as the duration of uat is not fixed.

The question is similar to the issue being discussed here
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/re-run-skipped-stages-1/1076765

Answer (score 0):

If you've manually removed a stage from the stage list there is no way to restart that stage. To prevent the prod stage from running automatically you could set an approval on an environment